# Disable spring boot actuator endpoints java config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I woud like to disable all actuator endpoints except for the health endpoint. All docs describe how to achieve this in the resource properties:

```
endpoints.enabled=false
endpoints.health.enabled=true
```

but I have always preferred to use inline java configuration. Could someone please explain where in the application I can configure the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at **org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.EndpointAutoConfiguration**, the endpoints are provided when the beans are missing. One option would be to provide them in your own configuration class. All endpoints have the field *enabled*. You could provide all of them, setting enabled on **false**, except for the one you need.

```
@Configuration
public class ActuatorConfiguration {

    @Autowired(required = false)
    private Collection<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics;

    @Bean
    public MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint() {
        List<PublicMetrics> publicMetrics = new ArrayList<>();
        if (this.publicMetrics != null) {
            publicMetrics.addAll(this.publicMetrics);
        }
        Collections.sort(publicMetrics,AnnotationAwareOrderComparator.INSTANCE);
        MetricsEndpoint metricsEndpoint = new MetricsEndpoint(publicMetrics);
        metricsEndpoint.setEnabled(false);
        return metricsEndpoint;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to give example of a sample bean that disables an endpoint?

Comment: edited my answer to give an example on how to disable the metricsendpoind. In the **EndpointAutoConfiguration** endpoint you can find all the other ones you could disable by *.setEnabled(false)*

Answer (score 1):

I found this question, wanted to post an update from / a reference to the current docs

I guess what you want to do would be something like this these days:

```
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=health
```

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.6.4/reference/htmlsingle/#actuator.endpoints.exposing