How to disable all management.observations for Spring Boot provided by Jhipster
I have updated my application to Jhipster 8.7.0 with jhipster upgrade command and have some issues with disabling observations at all for Spring boot, and it is requires me some beans which I do not want to use and i have the follow up exception:
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcObservationFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/web/servlet/WebMvcObservationAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcObservationFilter' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'observationRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/observation/ObservationAutoConfiguration.class]: Error creating bean with name 'defaultTracingObservationHandler' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/MicrometerTracingAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'defaultTracingObservationHandler' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'micrometerOtelTracer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'micrometerOtelTracer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'otelTracer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/OpenTelemetryAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'otelTracer' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'openTelemetry' defined in class path resource [com/aryza/ls/goodbook/config/OtelConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'openTelemetry' parameter 0: Error creating bean with name 'otelSdkLoggerProvider' defined in class path resource [com/aryza/ls/goodbook/config/OtelConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.opentelemetry.sdk.logs.SdkLoggerProvider]: Factory method 'otelSdkLoggerProvider' threw exception with message: Error creating bean with name 'otelLogProcessor' defined in class path resource [com/aryza/ls/goodbook/config/OtelConfiguration.class]: Failed to instantiate [io.opentelemetry.sdk.logs.LogRecordProcessor]: Factory method 'otelLogProcessor' threw exception with message: Receiver class io.opentelemetry.exporter.sender.okhttp.internal.OkHttpGrpcSenderProvider does not define or inherit an implementation of the resolved method 'abstract io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.GrpcSender createSender(java.net.URI, java.lang.String, boolean, long, java.util.Map, java.lang.Object, java.util.function.Supplier, io.opentelemetry.sdk.common.export.RetryPolicy, javax.net.ssl.SSLContext, javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager)' of interface io.opentelemetry.exporter.internal.grpc.GrpcSenderProvider.

How to disable  all management.observations for Spring Boot ?
this is  my code  in application.yaml file which i try to disabled it:
management:
  observations:
    enable:
     all: false

but it doesn't help, also i have this provided again by the upgrade in my application.yml file:
 observations:
    key-values:
      application: ${spring.application.name}

which i also tried to remove and still want to create some beans.
I just want to disable at all the management.observations ?

Maybe this answer will help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336812/disable-spring-boot-actuator-endpoints-java-config

@MattRaible Thanks, but doesn't helps.
